# Create a script using Blender and LuxRender Python API?

Tags: blender

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04.

Is it possible to create a script using Blender and LuxRender Python API? Can I use both APIs in the same script?

What should I install to start programming a script using their API if it is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Blender has python integrated into it very well and makes extensive use of it, it includes a python console and text editor to write and execute python scripts within Blender. Python access to Blender from outside of Blender is limited/experimental at best.

The Luxrender project provides a Blender addon called luxblend25, which is what you will want.

So you want to install Blender, Luxrender and luxblend25 and do your scripting within Blender. You also have the option to use an external text editor of your choice and open the script in Blender to run it. The luxblend25 scripts are in python and are your best examples of accessing the Luxrender engine from within Blender.

Blender now has it's own [stackexchange site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) - you may find it useful for blender specific help.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
In the Python API I didn't find a fonction or a way to render a scene(http://www.luxrender.net/static/pylux/). How could I render a scene thanks to luxrender in a python script ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pylux but within blender bpy.context.scene.render.engine contains the name of the render engine to be used. bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=False, layer="", scene="") will start the actual render.